# Codeigniter wrong pagination link

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

I'm creating a pagination using codeigniter. 
I want the link to be: **site_name/categorie_name/page/id** => id is dynamic.
When i create the pagination and when i'm on the page **site_name/categorie_name/page/1**. the next page link is replaced by **site_name/categorie_name/page/1/id**.
what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

```
public function Pagginations($total_row,$baseurl,$per_page) {        
        $config = array();
        $config["base_url"] = $baseurl;
        $config["total_rows"] = $total_row;
        $config["per_page"] = $per_page;
        $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
        //$config['num_links'] = 100;
        $config['uri_segment'] = 2 ;
        $config['num_links'] = 100;                
        $config['full_tag_open'] = "<ul class='pagination'>";
        $config['full_tag_close'] ="</ul>";
        $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['cur_tag_open'] = "<li class='disabled'><li class='active'><a href='#'>";
        $config['cur_tag_close'] = "<span class='sr-only'></span></a></li>";
        $config['next_tag_open'] = "<li>";
        $config['next_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
        $config['prev_tag_open'] = "<li>";
        $config['prev_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
        $config['first_tag_open'] = "<li>";
        $config['first_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
        $config['last_tag_open'] = "<li>";
        $config['last_tagl_close'] = "</li>";


        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        if ($this->uri->segment(2)) {
            $config['page']= $page = ($this->uri->segment(2));
        } else {
            $config['page']= $page = 1;
        }


        $config["links"]=explode('&nbsp;', $this->pagination->create_links());
        return $config;
    }
```

18 is display of product on one row

```
$config = $this->Pagginations($total_row,$baseurl,18);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But i need to fix my problem when creating link in the page site_name/categorie_name/page/1 because it's replaced by site_name/categorie_name/page/1/id